Build desktop application with a single file
I have a simple desktop application with just one project. Below the project settings
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>

When I build the project, I get a few files as below:
ProjectName1.exe
ProjectName1.dll
ProjectName1.deps.json
ProjectName1.runtimeconfig.json
What should I do to get a single exe file ProjectName1.exe as a build output instead of all these files?
I already tried the below, but it is not working. I am building from Visual Studio

    true
true
  
